# Equivalent to idiom 'Decency has been omitted from the dictionary'?

Tags: idiom-requests

The idiom 'That's it. Decency has been omitted from the dictionary.'
It means what is this world coming to no one is respecting anyone anymore. The sayer is suprised, for example it is said if even the young are being indecent and disrespectful to the elderly that know much better than them. There is no more decency and respect in this world.

Answer (score 4):

***"The world is going to hell in a hand-basket."***

Comment: There's a nice page on the phrase here http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/hell-in-a-handbasket.html

Comment: @Hugh - Interesting, thanks. I've said it aloud, but I had to think twice while writing it - it is an odd idea.